# fitting 2d polygons

Tags: algorithm

First of all I want to describe my problem: I have two 2D polygons (two sets of 2D point coordinates, polygonA and polygonB). I do not know if these two polygons collide or what is the distance between them. Moreover one of the polygons, say polygonA, is fixed, e.g. it is not allowed to translate or rotate it. Now I want to compute a position of polygonB such that
1. polygonA and polygonB do not collide
2. the summed squared distance between polygonA and polygonB is minimal
In other words: I am looking for a position where polygonB "perfectly" lies on polygonA.
Is there anybody who knows such an algorithm? Any ideas?
Thank you very much for your help!
Pia

Comment: Do you want to test if polyB lies completely in polyA, if polyB overlaps polyA, or what?  Not really sure what your objective is.

Comment: How do you calculate the distance between polygons? Are the polygons allowed to be concave or must they be convex? If you just need them to be touching surely there are many positions that would do that and you just need to choose one?

Comment: Oh! you are asking how to adjust the position of two polygons so that they no longer overlap.  Also, you probably don't want just to minimize the sum of the squares of the distances, you actually need to weight that so that small polygon colliding with a large one will be moved farther than the large one.  Either way, more descriptive tags would be a great help to those trying to help you solve the problem.  And finally, more details about the target system would also help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to determine if polyB lies completely within polyA, all you need to do is ensure all the boundary points of polyB lie within polyA.  Depending on what you want, either the Even-Odd Rule or the Non-Zero Winding Rule is what you should use to test that.  If you are only trying to test a partial overlap, all you need is for one of the verticies to lie within the other polygon, in that case, Even-Odd or Non-Zero is still the way to go.

Comment: No, I don't want to test if polyB lies completely in polyA! I want to compute the translation and rotation of polyB, such that polyA and polyB don't collide and summed squared distance between the two polygons is minimial. The case that polyB lies completey in polyA should also be excluded by the algorithm! I need a solution where polyB lies completely OUTSIDE of polyA!